# Difference between text-align: end and right

Tags: css, text-alignment

What is the difference between `text-align: end;` and `text-align: right;`?

When I use either one I get the same result, but is there any differences?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align:

> - `end`
>     The same as `right` if direction is left-to-right and `left` if direction is right-to-left.
> - `right`
>     The inline contents are aligned to the right edge of the line box.

Basically you use `end` in tandem to `direction: [rtl|ltr]` and `end` will adjust accordingly, whereas right will always keep your text to the `right` no matter what direction you set.

https://jsfiddle.net/ths4kdmx/

```css
.end {
  text-align: end;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.dir-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
.dir-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="dir-ltr end">
  End alignment in left-to-right direction
</div>
<div class="dir-rtl end">
  End alignment in right-to-left direction
</div>
<div class="dir-ltr right">
  Right alignment in left-to-right direction
</div>
<div class="dir-rtl right">
  Right alignment in right-to-left direction
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, never knew about this. Thanks, i couldn't find anyone ask on SO either.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, according to css-tricks:

> There are two new values in CSS3 as well, start and end. These values
> make multiple language support easier For example, English is a
> left-to-right (ltr) language and Arabic is a right-to-left (rtl)
> language. Using "right" and "left" for values is too rigid and doesn't
> adapt as the direction changes. These new values do adapt:
>
> 1: **start** - Same as "left" in ltr, same as "right" in rtl.
>
> 2: **end** - Same as "right" in ltr, same as "left" in rtl.

See detail here: [text-align in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)